# What is the correct way to calculate the covariate-specific effect in causal inference?

Tags: machine-learning, causality

My question is related to the concept named "Covariate-Specific Effects" in the book "Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer". In Section 3.3, it is called the "w-specific effect" and is calculated as:

$$
P(Y=y|do(X=x),W=w) = \sum_t P(Y=y|X=x, W=w, T=t) P(T=t|X=x,W=w).
$$

And in Section 3.5, it is called the "z-specific effect" and is calculated as:

$$
p(Y=y|do(X=x),Z=z) = \sum_s P(Y=y|X=x,S=s,Z=z) P(S=s|Z=z).
$$

I am a bit confused since both of the two formulas calculate the Covariate-Specific Effect but they are indeed different w.r.t the second term. Is this a mistake? What causes this difference?

Comment: My guess is that either Pearl intended to include $X=x$ in the $z$-specific effect, or he intended not to include it in the $w$-specific effect. I would lean towards the latter interpretation, since in the explanation immediately following your second equation, Pearl compares it to Eq. (3.5), but the differences don't mention the $X=x.$ There is no $X=x$ in Eq. (3.5) in the second term.

Comment: It seems like the second formula is used to calculate the covariate-specific effect in most cases, but how to derive it is not so straightforward. I think it would be more clear if we know how to derive these two formulas. Unluckily, the book didn't detail this.

Comment: Well, it's basically the adjustment formula. If you read the surrounding text, you can see his justification for the tweaks.

Comment: Yea, just look up the derivation of the adjustment formula, the rest follows from standard probability calculus.

Comment: Found the following [reliable errata page from Pearl's own UCLA website](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/PRIMER/). The errata [here](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/PRIMER/pearl-etal-2016-primer-errata-pages-august2021.pdf) changes the figure to replace $W \leftarrow X$ to $W \leftarrow V \rightarrow X$ and also suggests $P(T=t|W=w)$. In fact an [earlier version of this same errata page](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~kaoru/BIB5/pearl-etal-2016-primer-errata-pages-may2017.pdf) introduced $X=x$ in the first place.